Hide a nav menu item if a user hasn't purchased a specific product in WooCommerce and PHP
I am trying to write a PHP code that will hide an existing nav menu item called 'My English Course' if a logged in customer HAS NOT purchased a WooCommerce product with an ID of 426.
In other words, if they have purchased that product, the menu item called 'My English Course' will be shown, otherwise it should be hidden from them.
I have used the code below, but somehow it hides this menu item from all the users, even the ones that have purchased the product 426.
Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'hide_my_course_menu_item', 10, 2 );
function hide_my_course_menu_item( $items, $args ) {
    // Check if the user is logged in and hasn't purchased product with ID 426
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && ! has_user_purchased_product( get_current_user_id(), 426 ) ) {
        foreach ( $items as $key => $item ) {
            // Check if the menu item is 'My English Course'
            if ( $item->title == 'My English Course' ) {
                // Remove the menu item
                unset( $items[$key] );
            }
        }
    }
    return $items;
}

// Function to check if a user has purchased a product
function has_user_purchased_product( $user_id, $product_id ) {
    // Check if WooCommerce is active
    if ( class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) ) {
        // Get all completed orders for the user
        $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
            'meta_value'  => $user_id,
            'post_type'   => 'shop_order',
            'post_status' => 'wc-completed', // Completed orders
        ) );

        // Loop through orders to check for the product
        foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) {
            $order = wc_get_order( $customer_order->ID );

            // Check if the order contains the product
            if ( $order->has_product( $product_id ) ) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

